# Youtube Data API v3 java search with pagination issue

Tags: java, youtube-api, google-api-java-client

I am using the youtube data api v3, but I ma having a weird issue. I do understand that for pagination, I need to use the nextPageTokem from the response while sending the subsequent request, but my issue is that, I am not getting a nextPageToken in the response. My code is as below.

```
      youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {}
  }).setApplicationName("DMT").build();


  String queryTerm = "<my movie>";

  YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");


  String apiKey = properties.getProperty("youtube.apikey");
  search.setQ(queryTerm);
  search.setVideoDuration("long");

  search.setType("video");
  search.setFields("items(*)");
  SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
      System.out.println(searchResponse.toPrettyString());
      System.out.println(searchResponse.getNextPageToken());

  List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();


  if (searchResultList != null) {
      System.out.println(searchResponse.getPageInfo());
      prettyPrint(searchResultList.iterator(), queryTerm);
  }
```

What am I missing? Do I need to set some thing to get the header in the response?

Thanks in advance for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are setting fields to only return "items". If you want to only return items and nextpageToken, you can set it to "items,nextPageToken"

Comment: Thanks @Ibrahim Ulukaya, that helped. Is there any documentation for these things. The documentation for v3 looks very sparse other than some samples and javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Recursive function to print an entire feed.
 public static void printEntireVideoFeed(YouTubeService service, 
VideoFeed videoFeed, boolean detailed) throws MalformedURLException, 
IOException, ServiceException {
 do {
     printVideoFeed(videoFeed, detailed);
     if(videoFeed.getNextLink() != null) {
     videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(videoFeed.getNextLink().getHref()), 
     VideoFeed.class);
     }
 else {
        videoFeed = null;
       }  
    }
while(videoFeed != null);
 }
```

// Sample use of recursive function. Print all results for search term "puppy".

```
YouTubeQuery query = 
new YouTubeQuery(new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos"));
query.setFullTextQuery("puppy");
VideoFeed videoFeed = service.query(query, VideoFeed.class);
printEntireVideoFeed(service, videoFeed, false);
```